# Holomorphic buildings vs. compactification of moduli space of holomorphic curves

Tags: symplectic-geometry

Let $(W^{2n}, \Omega)$ be a symplectic cobordism from $(Y_+, \lambda_+, \omega_+)$ to $(Y_-, \lambda_-, \omega_-)$, where $(Y_+, \lambda_+, \omega_+)$  are  $(Y_-, \lambda_-, \omega_-)$ are manifolds with stable Hamiltonian structures. Let $\gamma_+$ and $\gamma_-$ be Reeb orbits of  $(Y_+, \lambda_+, \omega_+)$  and  $(Y_-, \lambda_-, \omega_-)$ respectively.
Let $\mathcal{M}^J(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, A)$ be the  moduli space of punctured holomorphic curves in $W$ whose positive punctures are asymptotic to $\gamma_+$ and negative punctures are asymptotic to $\gamma_+$. Moreover, the holomorphic curves in $\mathcal{M}^J(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, A)$  have a fixed homology class $A$.

In the paper "Compactness results in Symplectic Field Theory", its authors define the moduli space of holomorphic buildings $\mathcal{M}^{J}_{br}(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, A)$. Moreover, they show that any sequence of curves in   $\mathcal{M}^{J}(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, A)$ converges (after passing to a subsequence) to a limit in   $\mathcal{M}^{J}_{br}(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, A)$.
Let $\overline{\mathcal{M}^J(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, A)}$ be the compactification of  $\mathcal{M}^{J}(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, A)$ by adding the limit points in  $\mathcal{M}^{J}_{br}(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, A)$.

My question: Do we have $\overline{\mathcal{M}^J(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, A)}=\mathcal{M}^{J}_{br}(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, A)$? In other words, does any holomorphic building comes from the limit of a sequence of holomorphic curves? Is it possible that $\mathcal{M}^J(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, A)=\emptyset$ and $\mathcal{M}^{J}_{br}(\gamma_+, \gamma_-, A) \ne \emptyset$?